# How to print unclosed tags in PHPTAL Macros

Tags: php, html, phptal, template-metal

I'm in the process of transitioning a site to using PHPTAL templates, for now I am writing all new pages using templates while leaving the existing pages as is.

The older pages use a standard header and footer, a typical page has it's content generated like this:

```
printHeader();
//print page content
printFooter();
```

The new pages in PHPTAL will use the same standard header/footer so I'm moving them into macros. I want to use the same source HTML for both new and old page headers and footers. To accomplish this I want to edit the printHeader() and printFooter() functions to use a template to print the header and footer macros:

```
printHeader() {
   $source = '<metal:use-macro="macros.xhtml/header" />';
   $header = new PHPTAL()
   $header->setSource($source);
   echo $header->execute();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my header contains the opening `<html>` and `<body>` tags, which are closed in the footer. PHPTAL is throwing an exception because my macros are not valid xml:

```
Not all elements were closed before end of the document. Missing: </tal:block></tal:block></tal:block></body></html></tal:block>
```

What's the easiest way around this? I've found a workaround using structure to include these tags as a string but it seems sloppy:

```
<tal:block metal:define-macro="header">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<tal:block tal:content="structure string:&lt;html&gt;" />
   <head>
      head content
   </head>         
   <tal:block tal:content="structure string:&lt;body&gt;" />
      header content
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Maybe some sort of tal attribute that will allow it to ignore the missing closing tags for `<html>` and `<body>`?

Answer (score 1):

PHPTAL is designed to make outputting of malformed markup as hard as possible, and unclosed tags are malformed markup.

You should never have `printHeader`/`printFooter` functions. You need to flip this inside-out and have something like `printContent()` function and call it from template that includes both header and footer:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<title>Header is here</title>
<body>

  ${php:printContent()}

  <p>Footer is here</p>
</body>
```

(it doesn't have to be function, you can assign output to a variable, you can call a macro, and macro name can be variable too).